# C++11 calling constructor from constructor of same class type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, constructor, c++11

I was told the following was possible due to changes in C++11:

```
class SomeType  {
int number;

public:
SomeType(int new_number) : number(new_number) {}
SomeType() : SomeType(42) {}
};
```

But when I try to build I get an error:

```
"SomeType" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "SomeType"

error C2614: 'SomeType' : illegal member initialization: 'SomeType' is not a base or member
```

Is this feature not yet supported in Visual Studio 2010? Do I need to configure something to get this to build? What is wrong?

Comment: For future reference, these are known as _delegating constructors_.

Comment: by the way, it IS supported in gcc (mingw-w64, devc++, code::blocks, mingw, DJGPP)

Comment: @JimMichaels: reporting IDEs (code::blocks) is a bit surprising. I use code::blocks and clang...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not supported in VS2010. Most C++11 features are not supported in VS2010 (or VS11 for that matter)

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) is a chart of supported features in VC10 and VC11.

Comment: Frustrating! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Keep in mind that VS2010 came out long before the C++11 draft standard was even close to complete. I'd say we're lucky it supports what features it does. Lambda support in particular is a godsend.

Comment: @brendanw: C++11 had been in the works for quite some time. GCC 4.3 had support for rvalue references and variadic templates (for example) back in 2008, 3 years before VS10 shipped (And VS10 shipped *without* variadic template support, and now, in 2012, VS11 still has no support for it.) GCC had lambdas in 2010, a year before VS10 did (and the lambda's in VS10 are buggy). Now in 2012 VS11 is about to ship with poor C++11 support, while GCC 4.7 was released in March with almost full C++11 support. I don't think luck has a thing to do with it.

Comment: @brendanw: C++11 support is not a priority for VC++ (and M$). They cherry-picked the features *they* deemed interesting. Perhaps that it may change for the next release (as they actually decided to ask the community for the features they wanted), but they are far behind in terms of support; I guess there is no strong commercial incentive.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Herb Sutter, the chair of the C++ Standards committee is also chief native languages architect at Microsoft, and has been instrumental in getting them serious about standards.

Comment: @PeterWood: Oh, I know :) And it's great that they try to be more Standard compliant, definitely. On the other hand, VC++ does not seem to be ready to complete C++11 implementation any time soon either.

Comment: MS simply hasn't had the manpower dedicated to maintaining full standard compliance in a while. The STL, for instance, is implemented by Dinkumware and merely integrated by MS. The vast majority of development work on the DevStudio end has been on .NET. I think with Dev11, there is a return to a greater emphasis on native. MS is a big place though, and things move slowly.

Comment: @GManNick When GCC implemented those features, the C++0x standard was still in draft, and subject to change. Some parts have indeed changed since then. One thing MS is extremely loathe to do is incorporate changes that have potential to break user code. Building a feature set on a draft standard that was not yet concrete was too great a risk for them. Open source has fewer scruples about backwards compatibility.