# Illegal Member initialization

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, member-initialization

I am using this pretty simple class without using any inheritance.

```
class A
{
  int a;
  int b;

public:
 A(int x, int y) { a = x; b = y;}
 A() :A(0,0){};
 ~A(){};
} ;

int main ()
{
  A a1, a2(5, 7) ;
}
```

I get this error.

> error C2614: 'A' : illegal member initialization: 'A' is not a base or member

There are similar questions on SO but they relate to inheritance. Can someone explain the reason and what does standard say about that?

**EDIT:**

It would be better if someone elaborate more on the forwarding constructor and this feature in C++11.

Comment: This compiles fine for me but not in gcc

Comment: looks like you're using Visual Studio 2010(or previous), it doesn't work in VS2010 even. I heard that more features of C++11 have been added to SP1, and VS2012 but I am not too sure.

Comment: See [n1986](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986.pdf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 calling constructor from constructor of same class type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423401/c11-calling-constructor-from-constructor-of-same-class-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++11, you could initialize `A()` from `A(int, int)`. This is not possible in C++03, where you have to write two separate constructors.

If you want your code to work in C++03, you have two options:

- Create a function `init(int, int)` and call it from each of your constructors. This is a good choice if your constructor does a lot of work.
- Duplicate behaviour in both constructors. This is a good choice when all you are doing are member initializations.

You can also call a base constructor from a child class constructor. For instance, if you have

```
class A {
    A(int, int);
};
class B : public A {
    B(int, int);
};
```

You could write

```
B::B(int x, int y) : A(x,y) {}
```

This is what your compiler means when it says that `A is not a base`, it is expecting this situation.

All of these are compatible with C++03.

You could also upgrade your compiler to support C++11 features. I wouldn't recommend this if you are working in Linux and want your project to compile in Windows because Windows compilers don't implement all the C++ features that Linux compilers do (unless you pay for a good compiler).

Answer (score 1):

that's because of your problem with the constructor at :

From the looks of your error message, I am assuming you're on Visual Studio (probably 2010) and I agree, it doesn't work in VS2010.

```
A:A(0,0){ }
```

Fix for VS 2010 and its predecessors: `A():a(0),b(0){}`

Comment: now it this is valid C++11, it's called constructor chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this way `A() :A(0,0){};` this way is used to initialize class base members.

```
A(){a=0;b=0;};
```

or if you wish define `private: void set(int x, int y);` and use it in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a delegating constructor, which is a language feature that was only introduced in `C++11`, and which is not yet implemented in every compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`A() :A(0,0){};`  is called constructor chaining.

You should check that you compiler accept C++11. Constructor chaining is only valid in C++11. It was not available before.

What compiler do you use ?

Comment: maybe Miscrosoft has not implemented it yet. Only a part of C++11 is supported by VS2010.