# Convert small bit of code from c++11 to c++03?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

I'm a social scientist trying to compile C++ code, and hitting small problem I think is trivially easy to fix if you know C++, but inscrutable to me.

Trying to compile on V2008, but my code seems to use some C++11 syntax tricks.

[In principle, I think this is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988048/illegal-member-initialization), but I really don't understand C++ so not sure how to implement.

Code block:

```
Optimiser::Optimiser(double eps, double delta, unsigned long max_itr, long random_order)
{
  this->eps = eps;
  this->delta = delta;
  this->max_itr = max_itr;
  this->random_order = random_order;
}

Optimiser::Optimiser() : Optimiser::Optimiser(1e-5, 1e-2, 1000, 1)
{
  //ctor
}
```

And the error I get (referring to the Optimiser::Optimiser() : Optimiser::Optimiser(1e-5, 1e-2, 1000,1) line) is:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
src\Optimiser.cpp(39) : error C2039: '{ctor}' : is not a member of 'Optimiser'        include\Optimiser.h(26) : see declaration of 'Optimiser'
src\Optimiser.cpp(40) : error C2614: 'Optimiser' : illegal member initialization: 'Optimiser' is not a base or member
error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: If you use different names between constructor parameters and data members, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax.

Comment: Did you consider upgrading your compiler (or switching to a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegating constructors were not allowed until C++11. That being said, you'll be duplicating code but you can simply change your second constructor to

```
Optimiser::Optimiser()
{
    eps = 1.0e-5;
    delta = 1.0e-2;
    max_itr = 1000UL;
    random_order = 1L;
    //rest of your ctor
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably most straightforward solution is to remove current default constructor and provide default arguments in the other one

```
class Optimiser {
    public:
        Optimiser(double eps = 1e-5, double delta = 1e-2, unsigned long max_itr = 1000, long random_order = 1);
    ...      
 }
```

Constructor definition may stay as it is, although it's better to use initialization list

```
Optimiser::Optimiser(double p_eps, double p_delta, unsigned long p_max_itr, long p_random_order):
    eps(p_eps),
    delta(p_delta),
    max_itr(p_max_itr),
    random_order(p_random_order)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend changing this:

```
Optimiser::Optimiser() : Optimiser::Optimiser(1e-5, 1e-2, 1000, 1)
{
  //ctor
}
```

to this:

```
Optimizer::Optimizer()
: eps(1.0e-5), delta(1.0e-2), max_itr(1000), random_order(1)
{
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, initialization lists are also a C++11 feature

Comment: Initialization lists are in C++03 and C++11.  Many features in C++03 are also in C++11, that you can't get around, such as `std::string`.

Comment: @Cyber initialization lists are old feature. Probably you are confused with initializer lists.